# Why are animations from an Animated PDF not showing?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, pdf

I am going to prepare PDF presentation, with some basic animations, using LaTeX. A classic example can be found [here](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf).

I am able to view animations only when I view the PDF from my PC. No animations are showing while the viewing the PDF in Android. Is it a problem of my device (i.e., LG Optimus L5 with Ice Cream Sandwich) or does Android itself not support this? (e.g., some restrictions like opening a .zip attachment).

I am using Adobe Reader version 10.3.2, build 67615; it shows the images but not animations, while other readers like Polaris Office and Kindle Reader are unable to show the images also.

Could someone explain why this is? Am I missing something? How can I view these animations?

Comment: Showing animated GIF is noting to do with the Android or for the matter any operating systems. The application with which these GIFs are viewed should do it. If you had already tried Adobe Reader, try ezPDF which in my opinion is way better than other PDF readers.

Comment: @Narayanan: Kindly look the sample more closely. It was not a gif file embedded in PDF, rather it was compiled through `LaTeX`!

Comment: My mistake. Terribly sorry.

Comment: The only possible solution is to keep trying every possible app until you ran out of options. I use proOfficeSuite that somewhat supports powerpoint animations, not sure about LaTex though. It reads PDF files too.